# GridvView.SelectedCells.Add() does not update view

Tags: wpf, xaml, gridview

GridViews Selected cells is a IList, so it does not update the view, when i add selections from my ViewModel.

Is there a way to force updating the view for selected Cells. The way i currently uddate views is by having a Attached behavior, which updates the list on ViewModel, but also the GridView, but the GridView does not update its visuals.

here is my attached behavior:

```
   public static List<GridCell> GetSelectedCells(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (List<GridCell>)obj.GetValue(SelectedCellsProperty);
    }
    public static void SetSelectedCells(DependencyObject obj, List<GridCell> value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(SelectedCellsProperty, value);
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedCellsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("SelectedCells", typeof(List<GridCell>), typeof(DataGridHelper), new UIPropertyMetadata(null, OnSelectedCellsChanged));
    static SelectedCellsChangedEventHandler GetSelectionChangedHandler(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (SelectedCellsChangedEventHandler)obj.GetValue(SelectionChangedHandlerProperty);
    }
    static void SetSelectionChangedHandler(DependencyObject obj, SelectedCellsChangedEventHandler value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(SelectionChangedHandlerProperty, value);
    }
    static readonly DependencyProperty SelectionChangedHandlerProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(nameof(SelectedCellsChangedEventHandler), typeof(SelectedCellsChangedEventHandler), typeof(DataGridHelper), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    private static bool NewResouce = false;
    static void OnSelectedCellsChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (d is DataGrid)
        {
            NewResouce = true;
            DataGrid datagrid = d as DataGrid;
            if (GetSelectionChangedHandler(d) == null)
            {
                SelectedCellsChangedEventHandler selectionchanged = (sender, e) =>
                {
                    if (!NewResouce)
                    {

                        List<GridCell> cells = new List<GridCell>();
                        foreach (var selectedell in datagrid.SelectedCells)
                        {
                            string header = selectedell.Column.Header.ToString();
                            GridCell cell = new GridCell
                            {
                                RowIndex = datagrid.Items.IndexOf(selectedell.Item),
                                ColumnIndex = selectedell.Column.DisplayIndex,
                                Parent = selectedell.Item as ExpandoObject,
                                ColumnHeader = header,
                                Value = (selectedell.Item as IDictionary<string, object>)[header]
                            };
                            cells.Add(cell);
                        }
                        SetSelectedCells(d, cells);
                    }
                };
                SetSelectionChangedHandler(d, selectionchanged);
                datagrid.SelectedCellsChanged += GetSelectionChangedHandler(d);
            }

            foreach (var selected in GetSelectedCells(d) as List<GridCell>)
            {

                DataGridCellInfo cell = new DataGridCellInfo(selected.Parent, datagrid.Columns[selected.ColumnIndex]);
                if (!datagrid.SelectedCells.Contains(cell))
                {
                    datagrid.SelectedCells.Add(cell);
                }

            }

            NewResouce = false;
        }

    }
}
```

The reason why i have the NewResource boolean, is that the event selection changed does actually fire when I add newly selected items. Its just the view that does not update its selections.

The SelectedCells is added after the view is loaded, due to its located inside a tab, and it looks like the data on gridview is empty before view is loaded, so I cannot set selected before the view is loaded.

Comment: what u r trying to do finally ?

Comment: Just selecting stuff from viewmodel, by binding a selected cells list, however i figured it out, i should get DataGridCell instead and just set them to IsSelected and that fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is simple. Please use an ObservableCollection instead of the list. 
The observable collection is a dependency object and it will raise a propertyChanged event to the view to notify it regarding the property change and the view will be updated.

Comment: I didn't create GridView its already existing in WPF, so i cannot choose what to use.

Comment: Still if you can use the ObservableCollection instead of the list, it is supposed to work

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finden some properties that does implement INotifyPropertyChanged, on DataGridCells heres the solution:

```
static void OnSelectedCellsChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (d is DataGrid)
        {

            DataGrid datagrid = d as DataGrid;
            if (GetSelectionChangedHandler(d) == null)
            {
                SelectedCellsChangedEventHandler selectionchanged = (sender, e) =>
                {


                        List<GridCell> cells = new List<GridCell>();
                        foreach (var selectedell in datagrid.SelectedCells)
                        {
                            string header = selectedell.Column.Header.ToString();
                            GridCell cell = new GridCell
                            {
                                RowIndex = datagrid.Items.IndexOf(selectedell.Item),
                                ColumnIndex = selectedell.Column.DisplayIndex,
                                Parent = selectedell.Item as ExpandoObject,
                                ColumnHeader = header,
                                Value = (selectedell.Item as IDictionary<string, object>)[header]
                            };
                            cells.Add(cell);

                        }
                        SetSelectedCells(d, cells);


                };
                SetSelectionChangedHandler(d, selectionchanged);
                datagrid.SelectedCellsChanged += GetSelectionChangedHandler(d);
            }

            foreach (var selected in GetSelectedCells(d) as List<GridCell>)
            {

                    DataGridCell actualCell = datagrid.GetCell(selected.RowIndex, selected.ColumnIndex);
                    actualCell.IsSelected = true;
                    actualCell.Focus();
                }

            }

        }
```

for it to work i added some extention method to datagrid, to make it easier to get the Cell here the extention methodes: (stolen from this [blog](http://techiethings.blogspot.com/2010/05/get-wpf-datagrid-row-and-cell.html))

```
   public static T GetVisualChild<T>(Visual parent) where T : Visual
    {
        T child = default(T);
        int numVisuals = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
        for (int i = 0; i < numVisuals; i++)
        {
            Visual v = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
            child = v as T;
            if (child == null)
            {
                child = GetVisualChild<T>(v);
            }
            if (child != null)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        return child;
    }
    public static DataGridCell GetCell(this DataGrid grid, int rowIndex, int columnIndex)
    {
        return GetCell(grid, GetRow(grid, rowIndex), columnIndex);
    }
    public static DataGridCell GetCell(this DataGrid grid, DataGridRow row, int column)
    {
        if (row != null)
        {
            DataGridCellsPresenter presenter = GetVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(row);

            if (presenter == null)
            {
                grid.ScrollIntoView(row, grid.Columns[column]);
                presenter = GetVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(row);
            }

            DataGridCell cell = (DataGridCell)presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(column);
            return cell;
        }
        return null;
    }
    public static DataGridRow GetRow(this DataGrid grid, int index)
    {
        DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index);
        if (row == null)
        {
            // May be virtualized, bring into view and try again.
            grid.UpdateLayout();
            grid.ScrollIntoView(grid.Items[index]);
            row = (DataGridRow)grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index);
        }
        return row;
    }
```